# Facebook Device Login With Samsung Smart TV

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, samsung-smart-tv

I want to use facebook login with my samsung smart tv app.
To do that i want to use facebook device login.

The information i found is in this link
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/using-login-with-devices/

Is it possible to login in your app using facebook device login.
Or is there any other sdk or way to do a facebook connect in your smart tv app

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Samsung does not provide any API for Facebook or Twitter login inside the applications. 
The native Facebook application preinstalled on all SmartTV devices operates using a private API, which can't be shared with 3rd parties.

The official Facebook login API for app developers is incompatible with SmartTV platform, as it requires to open a new browser window for login - this feature is not supported on any of device.

Comment: Facebook is using one device log in to allow using  facebook   api calls the link is : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/using-login-with-devices/  ..  Does Samsung Smart TV is a partner there  ?

Answer (score 0):

I used facebook login with devices on Samsung Smart TV, it works, but only with partners facebook appID, i used appID from  source code of test example.
Samsung TV doesn't provide any way to login yet. Preinstalled Facebook application uses old facebook rest api, which deprecated since 2012. All old applications, that was created befor 2012 has the ability to makes rest api request, but new applications not. 
Summary: we don't have any official general way to login on Facebook. Follow updates for Facebook OAuth.

Comment: @llya Z it means i have no way other then wait :(

Comment: @Suresh Bora yes, unfortunately  :(