# Facebook login from Samsung SmartTV

Tags: facebook, samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv, lg

I have been experimenting with Samsung and LG smartTV specially for Facebook based login.

After searching rigorously over LG and Samsung dev forum and StackOverflow, I couldn't come up with any solution. Later I created a prototype app with the following strategy -

- I have a simple application, with a welcome screen and a big "Connect with Facebook" button
- Once user click over "Connect with Facebook" it redirects to Facebook login page.
- Later user enters email and password
- After successful login Facebook redirects back to our online hosted application page with access_token
- Then we have an angularjs based app which just do some Facebook graph call and show as proof of success.

I have integrated the above strategy in both LG and Samsung TV. LG seems to be working with Emulator, If I use `window.NetCastSystemKeyboardVisible(true);` which shows the native keyboard on redirected (Facebook login page).

But I couldn't find anything similar to `window.NetCastSystemKeyboardVisible(true);` for Samsung Smart TV.

So my question is,

Am I doing it right ? Or Am I missing something obvious that someone knows already ?

Regards

Comment: Pls see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21621605/2068612

Comment: thanks @llyaZ it explains everything. I checked Samsungdev forum which mostly refers to old REST api and it's long gone. at least after 2013 September it was officially stopped according to facebook.

But due to the reality my approach was simply redirecting to facebook login url, so after successful login it should redirect back to our redirect_url. 

But things seems quite ok and it should have been working. But using Emulator we couldn't get the Virtual keyboard over the redirected page. 

Any comment on this regards ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to set up login on Facebook through a SmartTV for third party applications. At the moment its not available even by accessing FB data using the SSO option. The Facebook app on SmartTV uses the old FB API, now deprecated and available to Samsung by a specific agreement between the two parties.

Comment: hi @andrea-f thanks for pointing this. ic. do you think this old facebook REST api still works on samsung devise ?

I couldn't get it working over the emulator though.

Comment: Hi @WellTreatUs it does work on the device but its a native app, so basically to use the same API you would need to sign a contract with Facebook.

Comment: hi @andrea-f it makes sense though. thanks for the answer. let me know if you find anything.

Btw, do you know the clue how to show up the keyboard over the redirected page. if i could nailed this problem like LG i should have been done.

Comment: @WellTreatUs you can try to look at this page and see if it might be useful for you: http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/tut00024/index.html 
It is about convergent apps. Unless you are a certified - ie you have a specific agreement with Samsung as VOD provider - you can't use the API that lets you open a webbrowser window from an app. Try experimenting with the NScreen API though.

Comment: hi @andrea-f thank you again :) 

You are right i assume, because we tried two apps today. "Social TV" which signs in through samsung account. (I assume through samsung SSO api).

Then Spotify, which has it's own Facebook authentication dialog. Even it used it's own keyboard interface. 

Any clue what is the strategy for spotify ?

Regards

Comment: Ah! I did not know about this possibility through Spotify. The obvious answer would be Spotify has a contract with Facebook to use the old API. To investigate matters further you can check the Wireshark trace on tv traffic when is doing this login exchange, that might give more clues on how they are doing it.

Comment: hi @andrea-f thanks for reminding me about the packet sniffing but i live far far away from our test TV :) otherwise i could do that. 

But i agree with you, there must be some exceptional case out there. 

Anyway thanks for sticking by.